# Storing a variable collection of strings in Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, c#-4.0

I would like to store a collection of strings in the web.config. This collection would vary in size over time. I would like to be able to pull all of the strings in the collection into an array or collection in code. (.Net 4, asp.net)
i.e.

```
<customCodes>
<VendorCode vendorName="Name1" code="1234567891234567891324567987ddd" isActive="true"/>
<VendorCode vendorName="Name2" code="1sadfsadf1234567891324567987ddd"  isActive="true" />
<VendorCode vendorName="Name3" code="123456789dfadfdsaf3324567987d32"  isActive="true"/>
</customCodes>
```

I could use appsettings with the strings all in one value but I would like to seperate it out for organizational reasons.

Any code snippets or examples would be appreciated.

*Sorry this was posted without the code example the first time. Not using the key/value pair complicates things a bit. I am now getting a message that states "**you can't have duplicate elements in a section**"*

TIA
J

Comment: You should really try to accept some of your old answers, or the community will not be as willing to help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom configuration section handler:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

For collections have a look at the ConfigurationElementCollection

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx

Following the second link a little deeper there is the code you need to to solve your problem. Just change somes tags and use "Add" instead of "VendorCode" :-)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationcollectionattribute.aspx

Comment: thanks both of the links have gotten me further down the path. The issue that I am running into now is that I keep getting an error about having the same parameter name in the web.config more than once.

Answer (score 0):

The link  http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/customconfiguration/Custom_Configuration_Collections.aspx was very helpful in accomplishing what I wanted to do. 
I did have to settle for using the "Add" tags instead of the custom tags that I origianally wanted.

Thanks for the help Dirk.

J